# ¿Cómo Bloqueo un Radiobutton en este caso?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radiobutton

```
def ventanaPrincipal():

    Tk.update(ventana)


    ventana.title('---------------Datos----------------')

    labelMain = Label(ventana, image=fondo1).place(x=0, y=0)

    casilla1 = StringVar()  # PARA QUE LAS CASILLAS ESTEN GRISES CUANDO SELECCIONO.
    casilla2 = StringVar()
    casilla3 = StringVar()
    casilla4 = StringVar()
    casilla5 = StringVar()
    casilla6 = StringVar()
    casilla7 = StringVar()
    casilla8 = StringVar()

    selecciona1 = Radiobutton(ventana, text='Pieza1', value='NeGranHuR', variable=casilla1, indicatoron=0,
                              command=lambda: clase.mifigura(casilla1.get())).place(x=668, y=120)

    selecciona2 = Radiobutton(ventana, text='Pieza2', value='NePequeHuR', variable=casilla2, indicatoron=0,
                              command=lambda: clase.mifigura(casilla2.get())).place(x=724, y=120)

    selecciona3 = Radiobutton(ventana, text='Pieza3', value='NeGranR', variable=casilla3, indicatoron=0,
                              command=lambda: clase.mifigura(casilla3.get())).place(x=780, y=120)
```

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so] Alicia. ¿Qué quieres decir con "bloquear" un RadioButton? ¿Inhabilitarlo para que no pueda ser seleccionado?¿En qué condiciones? Por cierto, si aplicas el método `place` en la misma linea que instancias el widgets, `labelMain`,  `selecciona1`, `selecciona2`, etc contiene el retorno de este método, `None`,  por lo que estas variables no sirven para nada y no puedes hacer referencia a los widgets posteriormente. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que yo selecciono el radiobutton y obtengo el valor que le estoy dando. Pero necesito que una vez que yo ya le haya dado click se bloquee (inhabilite) y no me permita volver a seleccionarlo.

Comment: Estoy utiizando tkinter (python)

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres evitar que un `RadioButton` que ha sido seleccionado siga respondiendo llamando a su callback cuando se hace click en él, lo más simple es deshabilitarlo. Esto lo puedes hace mediante el método `config` y el atributo `state`.

Primero de todo, es importante indicar que lo siguiente:

```
selecciona1 = Radiobutton(...).place(...)
```

no tiene demasiado sentido. El identificador `selecciona1` va a hacer referencia al retorno del método `place`, el cual retorna None. Esto causa que `selecciona1` sea una variables inútil al no hacer referencia a un widget sini a `None`. Si no vas a necesitar hacer referencia al widget con posterioridad, basta con hacer:

```
Radiobutton(...).place(...)
```

Si necesitas guardar una referencia al widget, para luego usar su método `config` por ejemplo, separa la instancia del widget de la llamada a su método place (igual pasa con `grid` y  `pack`):

```
selecciona1 = Radiobutton(...)
selecciona1.place(...)
```

Para desactivar el RadioButton de turno puedes crear una función que se encargue de desactivarlo y de llamar a `clase.mifigura`, un ejemplo reproducible basado en tu código:

```
import tkinter as tk




def ventana_principal():

    casilla1 = tk.StringVar() 
    casilla2 = tk.StringVar()
    casilla3 = tk.StringVar()

    def rb_command(radio_button, str_var):
        radio_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        clase.mifigura(casilla3.get())

    selecciona1 = tk.Radiobutton(ventana, text='Pieza1', value='NeGranHuR',
                                 variable=casilla1, indicatoron=0,
                                 command=lambda: rb_command(selecciona1, casilla1)
                                 )

    selecciona2 = tk.Radiobutton(ventana, text='Pieza2', value='NePequeHuR',
                                 variable=casilla2, indicatoron=0,
                                 command=lambda: rb_command(selecciona2, casilla2)
                                 )

    selecciona3 = tk.Radiobutton(ventana, name="rb3", text='Pieza3', value='NeGranR',
                                 variable=casilla3, indicatoron=0,
                                 command=lambda: rb_command(selecciona3, casilla3)
                                 )

    selecciona1 .place(x=10, y=120)
    selecciona2.place(x=66, y=120)
    selecciona3.place(x=122, y=120)



class Foo:
    def mifigura(self, string):
        print("Llamada")    

ventana = tk.Tk()
clase = Foo()
ventana_principal()
ventana.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Nota:** No se que razón tienes para llamar a `update` en la función, pero hay que tener cuidado desde donde se llama este método ya que puede ocasionar comportamientos inesperados al provocar condiciones de carrera, por ejemplo cuando es llamado desde una callback de evento.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Ya me funcionó